# How to quickly update connected textures in Blender?

Tags: texturing, interface, add-on, import, shortcut

I work with textures in Substance Painter and every time I make changes and export textures from SP to a folder, I have to re-select a new texture map file in the "Image Texture" node in the Shader Editor window. Doing it manually is very time consuming.
However, if I close and reopen the .blend file, Blender will load the new textures from the folder. This is a very inconvenient way, but for some reason I can't find the texture refresh button in Blender itself.
What solutions might this problem have? Addons, plugins, maybe a feature in Blender itself?

[image]

Comment: In the Image Editor (or UV Editor) you can select an image and go into Image > Reload (or Alt R), I don't know if it's possible for several images. Or you can save then File > Revert and it will reload all the images (no need to close Blender)

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit it, but I didn't know about the Reload button, it will be useful. 
The Revert way also looks better than just opening and closing Blender.
Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Image Editor* (or *UV Editor*) you can select an image and go into *Image > Reload* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), but I don't know if it's possible for several images.

Or you can save the file then *File > Revert* (you can create a shortcut for the *Revert* operation by the way, right click on it) and it will reload all the images (no need to close Blender).